# l don't get the meaning of the sentence in bold clearly

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> The bullet smashed Anders’ skull and ploughed through his brain and exited behind his right ear,
>   scattering shards of bone into the cerebral cortex, the corpus callosum, back toward the basal
>   ganglia, and down into the thalamus. But before all this occurred, the first appearance of the bullet
>   in the cerebrum set off a crackling chain of ion transports and neuro-transmissions. Because of
>   their peculiar origin these traced a peculiar patter, **flukishly calling to life a summer afternoon some
>   forty years past, and long since lost to memory**. After striking the cranium the bullet was moving at
>   900 feet per second, a pathetically sluggish, glacial pace compared to the synaptic lighting that
>   flashed around it. Once in the brain, that is, the bullet came under the mediation of brain time,
>   which gave Anders plenty of leisure to contemplate the scene that, in a phrase he would have
>   abhorred, “passed before his eyes".

Dose the whole phrase means: He remembered 40 years ago. and remembered things(a summer afternoon) that he completely had forgotten.?

Or Dose it means: He was forty years old.?

Or does it mean: suddenly he died in a summer afternoon?

Dose calling to life means: remembering?

(Bullet in the Brain by Tobias Wolff)

Comment: Your first paraphrasing is correct. Note that ***calling to life*** implies means the experience was so vivid / lifelike it was more like ***re-living the experience** (as if it were actually happening **again**)* rather than "remembering" it (as a "memory").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> flukishly calling to life

[The bullets passed through his brain] fortunately, or even surprisingly, rekindling a vivid memory...

> a summer afternoon some forty years past

...of a summer afternoon forty years ago...

> and long since lost to memory

...that had been forgotten a long time ago (by Anders).